# How can I know if item is selected inside the ItemTemplate?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatemplate, itemtemplate

I have a `ListBox` that use my custom `ItemTemplate`. I want to set `Visibility` property in my `TextBlock` (inside my template) depending on selected item. I think of doing it using triggers. But how can I know inside my template if current item is selected or not?

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="myTemplate">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image Tag="{Binding priority}" Loaded="SetIconPriority"/>
        <Image Tag="{Binding alarm}" Loaded="SetIconAlarm"/>
        <!-- I want this TextBlock to be visible only when item is selected -->
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding description}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

edit:
It works, thanks! Code:

```
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding opis}">
                <TextBlock.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBoxItem}}" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </TextBlock.Style>
            </TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a [`RelativeSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.relativesource.aspx) binding with `AncestorType` being `ListBoxItem`.

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected,
                               RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBoxItem}}"
             Value="True">
```

(May want to reverse the logic and `Collapse` on `False` instead, avoids the default value `Setter`)